# Count per category

Tags: sql, sybase

have a table as below -

```
COL1  |  COL2  |  COL3
1        1        1
1        1        2
1        2        0
1        2        1
2        3        1
2        3        2
2        4        0
2        4        1
3        1        0
3        2        0     
.
.
.
```

I want to select COL1 where all COL2 have sum(COL3) is > 0. If I am sure there are 20 distinct values in COL2, Then how can i pull all COL1 values that have all 20 COL2 filled with COL3 > 0. So the end result should be

```
COL1  |  COL2  |  COL3
1        1        3
1        2        1
2        3        3
2        4        1
```

I have tried a lot of ways to do this but no success.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I have tried a lot to solve this but the real challenge is to remove all  COL3 with 0 and then use Group by.

Comment: You have your answer below.

Comment: The answer doesn't ensures that All Distinct COL2 will have SUM(COL3) > 0. The real challenge.

Comment: I attempted a query below which I think might be what you are looking for.  It requires aggregating twice to get an answer.

Comment: `I have updated my requirements` ... but I won't update my answer.  Stack Overflow is not an ongoing forum where you keep changing your question, and at your rep level, you should know this.  Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree, hard to hit a moving goalpost.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `group by` and `having`.

```
select col1,col2,sum(col3)
from tbl
group by col1,col2
having sum(col3)>0
```

Comment: How will this this ensure that All Distinct COL2 will have SUM(COL3) > 0.

Answer (score 0):

I use a `CTE` and a `Group by` with a `where` condition

```
;WITH CTE as (
select COL1,COL2,SUM(COL3) as COL3  FROM table1  
Group By
COL1,COL2
)
select * from CTE 
where COL3>0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*
from yourTable t1
inner join
(
    select t.col1
    from
    (
        select col1, col2, sum(col3) as col_sum
        from yourTable
        group by col1, col2
    ) t
    group by t.col1
    having sum(case when t.col_sum = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
) t2
    on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just group col2 and check if it's bigger then 0

```
select col1,col2,sum(col3)
from tbl
group by col2
having sum(col3)>0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/537f8c/1

Answer (score 0):

See if the below gives you the result that you are after. It is selecting the col1, col2 and a sum of col3 from a derived(?) table that is excluding the col3's that are 0:

```
select col1, col2, sum(col3)
from
(
    select col1, col2, col3 from tbl where col3 <> 0
) as ds
group by col3
```